# How redirect from controller to another controller to POST method?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have some method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "process", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView process(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView;
        String phoneNumber = request.getParameter("phone_number");
        int amount = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("amount"));

        String result = validateService.validate(phoneNumber, amount);

        if (!result.equals("OK")) {
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("start");
            modelAndView.addObject("result",result);
        }else {
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/check/process");
            modelAndView.addObject("phone_number",phoneNumber);
            modelAndView.addObject("amount",amount);
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

I need redirect to another controller to POST method. but I have an error

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported
```

It ist second controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/check")
public class CheckController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "process", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView process(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("check");
        String phoneNumber = request.getParameter("phone_number");
        int amount = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("amount"));
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Where I tried redirect

Comment: tl;dr you cannot, if you need this, you just don't really understand how http works, you can explain your use case, then we may help you to find out a valid solution

Comment: how can I call new controller from my method?

Comment: the question is why?

Comment: you can use `resttemplate` to do it, but i'm sure that is not  what you want

Comment: Do what is right one controller - one view?

Comment: @user5620472 don't duplicate your questions, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498304/how-pass-post-parameters-from-controller-to-another-controller-spring-mvc

Answer (score 1):

You cannot redirect to a post method, you should take a look at **Post/Redirect/Get design pattern**. If the validation in your first controller succeeds, you could use `RedirectAttributes` to redirect with flash data to your second controller, therefore you have to change the method of `/check/process` to `GET`.