# How pass POST parameters from controller to another Controller Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have `startController` and start view. In this view I input number and amount and validate it. If validation was successful, I want pass this parameters(number and amount) to another controller, and after that make some operations with it, in this controller. I see two way:

1. make this operations in first controller, in another methods and use second view for it. But my controller will very big and all logic will be this.
2. create second controller and second view and pass parameters to this controller.

I make this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class StartController {

    @Autowired
    private ValidateService validateService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView printWelcome() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("start");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "process", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView process(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView;
        String phoneNumber = request.getParameter("phone_number");
        int amount = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("amount"));

        String result = validateService.validate(phoneNumber, amount);

        if (!result.equals("OK")) {
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("start");
            modelAndView.addObject("result",result);
        }else {
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/check/process");
            modelAndView.addObject("phone_number", phoneNumber);
            modelAndView.addObject("amount",amount);
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

and if `result != OK` I redirect to new controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/check")
public class CheckController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "process", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView process(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("check");
        String phoneNumber = request.getParameter("phone_number");
        int amount = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("amount"));
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

But I need pass parameters with `RequestMethod.POST` and it will not work. How do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can return a `ModelAndView` with parameters as follow:

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/check/process?phone_number="+yourPhoneNumber+"&amount="+amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forward to go to a new controller right?
  "forward:/test2?param1=foo&param2=bar";
Please see below link for more details.
[Spring forward with added parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585216/spring-forward-with-added-parameters)